# Are there random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ such that $Z=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$ has a log-normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was wondering if anyone could come up with independent random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$ whose probability distribution is such that $Z=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$ has a log-normal distribution. Here the $X_i$'s have the same distribution and $N(>1)$ is non-random.

Comment: Is $N$ deterministic or random? Are the $X_i$'s independant ?

Comment: $N$ is arbitrary, but not random.  I was hoping for a solution that worked for any $N>1$.  I guess the only case that needs to be considered is $N=2$.

Comment: @tristan The $X_i$ are independent.  I see your point.  The problem would most likely depend on $N$.  Because if $X_1+X_2$ is log-normal then $X_1+X_2+X_3$ probably isn't.  Possibly the problem could be thought of as finding a random variable $X$ such that $X+Z$ is log-normal where $Z$ is log-normal.

Comment: The log-normal distribution is infinitely divisible which means that for any positive integer $N$ there exists a set of i.i.d. random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ such that $Z=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ is log-normal. This was proven by Olof Thorin in 1977 using generalized $\Gamma$-convolutions. [I can't get access to the paper though.](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03461238.1977.10405635)